# Does 'fight fading chances' make sense at all in this headline?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

Source:  http://www.espncricinfo.com/indian-premier-league-2016/content/story/1012889.html

Please look at the following headline that I don't understand. Please tell me what fight fading chances means.

Kings XI Punjab ***fight fading chances*** to stay alive

Does 'fight fading chances' make sense at all?

Comment: When I look at the linked source, the headline is "Kings XI's chances to stay alive fading", which makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Fading means that as time goes on, the chance of staying alive gets smaller and smaller. Despite this worsening situation, the king (s) is/are fighting for life.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. *fight* is a verb here.

What are they fighting? Fading chances.

They are trying to improve their chances to not be eliminated (to stay alive).